# Display Fragment between toolbar and BottomNav

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am new to Android App delevopment. I want to have the LinearLayout from my "fragment_home.xml" displayed between my Toolbar at the top and Bottom Navbar. It's currently on top of my toolbar and I can't seem to get it below.
Here is my code:

fragment_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/recent_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/recent_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#262626">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/purple_500"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:title="@string/username"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/black">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/userIconToolbar"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/user_pb_default" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="#404040"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_item_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_item_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

HomeFragment.java:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbarUserIconClick();

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_direct, R.id.navigation_groups, R.id.navigation_settings).build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);
    }

    public void toolbarUserIconClick()
    {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userIconToolbar);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Link To Profile Settings Here
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It currently looks like this:
[image: App screenshot]

Thanks for any help in advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make below mentioned changes in the `activity_main.xml`

```
<fragment
.
.
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
.
.
.
keep everything as it is.
/>
```

In the above example, I've constraint `fragment` with **Toolbar** and **BottomNavigationView** and set the height of fragment to **0dp** so that it will adjust between Toolbar and BottomNavigationView.

Answer (score 1):

In your `fragment` component in `activity_main.xml`, replace

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

with

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
```